# C# flipping mainwindow

Tags: forms, user-interface, animation, desktop-application, coin-flipping

this is my very first entry here, may it not be the last....
I am having a bit of a struggle with some GUI stuff.

I really have an animation up front my eyes and it should look like the following: using c# with desktop application.

This Form looks like a login window with server address, username and pw textboxes and with a connect button as well, so nothing special. Size wise it can be small or at least same as size as the turned window. doesnt matter at the end.

once you entered your credentials and all turns out to be fine, connection is there and valid.
The main Form is suppost to flip then (doesnt matter horizontal or vertical),
and shows you your options you got then in this newly window. kind of an animated sign, that you are logged in and have now these options.
But the flip is suppost to stay on the same place. Like a card flip or a coin flip, but just the whole form and it ends then at the same place as before.
(sounds really wired to explain)

This can also be done with a new form poping up, just with a animated turn over, no problem with that.

And this is exactly where I am stuck.
I really cant find any information on how this would look like in code or even in animation. 
I am using c# and the basic project started as a desktop application project, which it will be at the end.

Its been a while since my last coding, please be gentle. 
i know there are plenty of entries in here also in google as well, but i didnt found anything which will do this for the main window as a total. images etc: yes, but for the whole form: no.
Any help out there?
May be tehr eis a trick i am not aware of? Its been a while since the last coding work, I need to admit that.#greyhairsarecomming

many thanks in advance! much appreciated

kind regards TG

Comment: What technology is this application using? Winforms? Wpf?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754739/how-to-animate-a-window to get you started

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick replies. Application is DesktopApplication , I am not sure wether this includes WPF or not? I think I am not using WPF, or not knowingly....I got Windows.Forms a s a reference preloaded.

Comment: Well, WPF does have better support for the type of animation that you describe

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ddnt get it done, so i just changed the idea. Man ythanks for your comments guys!